# Why doesn't my Java application work with huge pages in Red Hat Linux?

Tags: java, linux, memory, jvm, huge-pages

I have tried this simple command:

```
 java -XX:+UseLargePages -Xms2g -version
```

I receive the error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve 
shared memory (errno = 12).
```

But without large pages it works OK.

meminfo output:

```
HugePages_Total:     0
HugePages_Free:      0
HugePages_Rsvd:      0
Hugepagesize:     2048 kB
```

Comment: As you can see you have 0 pages for the "HugePages_Total". So your OS cannot use Huge Pages as it is configured. You need to change the vm.nr_hugepages sysctl parameter to a number of pages to allocate. Set it in the adequate /etc config file and reboot to be sure the kernel is able to attribute that much memory for huge pages. After that if HugePages_Total is still 0, then you might not have enough RAM for the number of pages you want to reserve for huge pages. See also your OS doc for setting huge pages (it can be done even earlier in the boot process as grub parameter)

Answer (score 4):

There are two things required to get huge pages working on Linux (see [Oracle's Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/largememory-jsp-137182.html))
1)  The max amount of shared memory available shmmax needs to be greater than the JVM heap size.
2)  Huge pages need to be enabled and sufficiently available to support the JVM heap.

The runtime setting for shmmax is at /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax.

The runtime setting for number of hugepages is at /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages

If you want these settings to persist after a reboot they will need to be set via sysctl.

So if you specify a 4GB maximum heap, shmmax needs to be >= 4GB, and with 2MB pages nr_hugepages would need to be >= 2K.

Your command line should also specify the maximum heap size.

Comment: @user710818 did you verify that once you did the setup and before you launch your java program that meminfo is reporting "HugePages_Total" a total number of pages that is enough for you?

Answer (score -1):

It does not work because your huge pages are only 2MB (2048 kB) and your heap size is a minimum of 2 GB.

Comment: You tried a max heap or a min heap of 2KB? It is the max heap which matters. The default max heap depends on a lot of factors, but will certainly be larger than 2KB.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html

Comment: The 2MB in meminfo output is the size of 1 page (instead of the default 4k). So your answer is incorrect.